# Datagridview Combobox Column not displaying select combobox value

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datasource, windows-forms-designer

I am using a normal Datagridview but I have a problem with it.
This way I am filling data in my grid and adding combobox column to it

```
db.DataEntities ss = new db.DataEntities();
DataGridview1.DataSource = ss.table1.ToList();

if (!DataGridview1.Columns.Contains("dgcolUser"))
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dgcombocolUser = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    dgcombocolUser.Name = "dgcolUser";

    var listOfAllUsers = ss.secAccountInformations.ToList();
    dgcombocolUser.DataSource = listOfAllUsers;
    dgcombocolUser.DisplayMember = "AccountName";
    dgcombocolUser.ValueMember = "UserId";
    DataGridview1.Columns.Add(dgcombocolUser);
}

foreach ( DataGridViewRow dgr in DataGridview1.Rows)
{
    dgr.Cells["dgcolUser"].Value = dgr.Cells["PermittedUserId"].Value;
}
```

I am opening this Form in a MDI parent

```
Form1 frm = new Form1() { MdiParent = MdiForm1};
frm.Show();
```

when I open my form it not displaying any selected value in Comboboxcolumn
But when I open my Form frm1 not it MdiParent it display selected value in Comboboxcolumn

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Show();
```

so is this really happen because it shows data when i am showing my form without MdiParnet or is there any other reason due to which it is not happening
Please give me better suggesstion.. because showing form without MdiParent is not valid solution.

Comment: Not able to reproduce; also it does not sound too logical. The most likely reason for observing these two different behaviours is that, in one of them, the foreach loop is not reached (a crash happens before). Debug the code and confirm that this is the case. If still don't see the problem provide more clear information: write the whole code (if there is more in between the 3 snippets you posted), confirm that you mean frm.Controls.Add(DataGridView), etc.

Comment: @varocarbas thanks for comment... but there is nothing happening in between 3 snippets and no crash is happening .. although if any crash happpens than it too did not give correct output while showing it without Mdi Parent

Comment: OK. Note that if a "light crash" happens (e.g., doing dgr.Cells["dgcolUser"].Value = "thisVal" when "thisVal" is not an element of the combobox), no line of code after it will be analysed, but all the code before will be accounted for perfectly (= exactly what you are complaining about and what I cannot reproduce). Please, debug the code and confirm that the loop is reached at all (and that it iterates through all the cells without any problem).

Comment: As you say "thisVal" is not an element of Combobox it raise and exception and i handled that exception by DataError event because sometime "thisVal" is null. And after handeling exception it display all the values . But actual problem is it display only when it was not in Mdi Parent

Comment: ??!! (I am getting involved in long-conversations to no where lately for still not clear reason to me -> people asking for helping; getting it; but apparently not being happy with the reality and starting a discussion?!). If you run your code, as you posted it (with NO error handling code, like a try...catch) and you introduce a wrong value it will show the behaviour I have described, that is: all fine until this point but no further code lines will be executed. This is an example of what I called "light error", which does not have to happen with you in this part (was an example).

Comment: If still there is any unclear bit, please, ask as much as you need to understand what I mean; but intend to avoid the "this is like that" (by saying things not making too much sense), it is a pretty unpleasant experience to help someone acting like this -> why are you asking? And if you feel like knowing so much, you don't think that should prove your statements at all (mine is really easy to be crosscheck -> add a wrong value to your code and see the result). Don't misunderstand me: I love people to question things but, at least, by making valid points (and understanding the other person).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I believe you are populating the DGV on form Load event. If you move that code to Form Activated Event then this should work within MDI form